# Advice on which modal popup to use: ASP.NET AjaxControlToolkit vs jQuery plugin vs Greybox vs?

Tags: asp.net, javascript, ajax, user-interface, popup

This is all being done in an ASP.NET web forms application:

I need a modal popup that will show the user a preview of images that match a search criteria (e.g. they search for "dog" and the popup shows them all dog-related pictures).  The search results shouldn't be too long, but the popup should support the ability to scroll if necessary.  I also need to capture which image they selected and send that info back to the calling page.

I've taken a look at some of the options out there and am having a hard time deciding on which one to use.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

i prefer the use of jquery because it doesnt require the use of any server-side computations. also if the app ever ported to another technology other than asp.net it will still most likely work.

Answer (score 1):

I'm happy with [jqModal](http://dev.iceburg.net/jquery/jqModal/), the plugin it's really minimalistic (basically 2.97kb of JS, and 496bytes of css) and works great...

Answer (score 1):

don't use any modal plugins, create your own.

<div id="modal"></div>

## modal { position: absolute; top: 200px; left: 200px; z-index: 12; width: 200px; height: 100px; background: red; color: blue; }

Then you can have some javascript on it, I recommend jquery's draggable, and then put some element that you can click on it so it disappears.

Voilà!!!

Comment: the simplest form for disappearing elements, if you don't want to use any js frameworks, is to alter css display property. 

myelem.onclick = function() {
myelem.style.display = "none"; 
}

Answer (score 0):

I've been quite happy with the jQuery plug-in [Simple Modal](http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal/).

Answer (score 0):

I'd say go with ours; [Ajax Calendar Starter-Kit](http://ra-ajax.org/samples/Viewport-Calendar-Starter-Kit.aspx) (click the button to the lower left corner) but then again I am definitely biased...